# How to disable enfold theme editer?

Tags: wordpress

I am using additional editor plugin to manage editor content. so now I want to disable enfold theme provided editor ( Avia Editor ).
is that possible? & how?

Comment: yes, its possible

Comment: if you have idea then please can you suggest how is it done?

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: I want to disable avia editor & start using elementor plugin.

Comment: it is a plugin, go to plugins and disable it

Comment: Nop, Avia editor is default editor provided by enfold purchased theme.So, i can disable it like that.

Comment: it should be a default plugin provided by the theme, check your plugins please

Comment: I have checked, but it's not on the list of the plugin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163245/discussion-between-maulik-and-yahya-hussein).